# How to make a generic type that must inherit from a class with generic type in Blazor?

Tags: c#, generics, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to make a class that have 3 generic types and one of the types must inherit from that other class that have the other 2 generic types.

What I really need is that `IForm` inherits from `FormComponent` so it have all of it's methods implemented.

Form.razor

```
@typeparam TForm
@typeparam TModel
@typeparam TResult

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    @ChildContent
</EditForm>
```

Form.razor.cs

```
public partial class Form<TForm, TModel, TResult>  
    where TForm : FormComponent<TModel, TResult>
{

    [Parameter]
    public TForm FormRef { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<TResult> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public TModel Model { get; set; }

    // ... 
    // some other properties
}
```

FormComponent.cs

```
public abstract class FormComponent<TModel, TResult> : BaseDomComponent
{        
    [CascadingParameter]
    public TModel Model { get; set; }

    public abstract TResult OnValidSubmit();

    // ... 
    // some other properties   
}
```

Code from where I use Form

```
<Form Model="@Entity" FormRef="@_formRef" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <XYZForm @ref="_formRef" />
    <Button ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit">Submit</Button>
</Form>
```

But this gives me the error

> Error CS0314  The type 'TForm' cannot be used as type parameter 'TForm' in the generic type or method 'Form< TForm, TModel, TResult >'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TForm' to 'Core.Web.Base.FormComponent< TModel, TResult >'

I searched this error in alot of places but didn't found any case where there was 3 generic types. I also read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0314)  but couldn't use that to solve my case.

Comment: The code you show by itself will not cause this error.  Do you have another class that is inheriting from `Form` that includes the `TForm` generic type, but does not have the constraint?

Comment: @juharr The error only happens at compile time. No other place uses the `Form`, only using `Form` to render the blazor component

Comment: IMO you don't need to declare `@typeparam`s, they are already declared in your partial class

Comment: Sorry, it's not true, you have to declare `@typeparam`

Comment: I did it here but with only one typeparam : https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/blob/master/src/Aguacongas.TheIdServer.BlazorApp/Components/TokensGrid.razor.cs

Comment: Can you post the code where you use your  `Form` component ?

Comment: @aguafrommars just edited my question. Because I pass all the parameters, It should know what type is it and I wouldn't need to pass the generic types

Comment: Is `XYZForm` derived from `FormComponent<TModel, TResult>` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars yes, `public partial class XYZForm : FormComponent<MyEntity, Task>`

Comment: and how do you declare `_formRef` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars `public XYZForm _formRef;` as expected

Comment: I don't have other idea, may be an issue with the cascading param

Comment: did you try to declare `_formRef` with `public FormComponent<EntityType, ResultType> _formRef` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars did it now and still got the same error at compile time.

Comment: Is `Core.Web.Base` your namespace ?

Comment: @aguafrommars Is half of the name space, the real name space starts with the name of my compoany and project name and ends with `Core.Web.Base`

Comment: no other `FormComponent` declared elsewhere ? The error message should contains the fullname type. Maybe you don't include the good namespace

Comment: @aguafrommars No other `FormComponent`, the error message problem was because SO tried to parse <TModel, TResult> to html and it was hiddding, I edit my question so it's visible now.

Comment: What if you delete *bin*, *obj* and *.vs* folders ? And if you build the project with `dotnet builld`

Answer (score 2):

Just find out this issue is about blazor [not supporting type constraints](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8433) yet.

@juharr asked if I was using it in another place. I said no, but acctually I'm using it in the blazor component, and it doesn't have that support yet ;/

Comment: This has been implemented and will be available in 6.0 preview4+ https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/a4a3668c455fe87f731803e4d0b3abfbc4f22198

Answer (score 0):

Make your generic component a class component only. That way you can add your constraints

Comment: I can't, because I'm using blazor

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth sharing the workaround I found - simply add a code-behind file to your component and specify the constraints there.

Credits [to this answer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8433#issuecomment-545690917) that led me to success...

Steps to add the constraint to `MyComponent.razor`:

1. Add -> New -> Class, name the file  `MyComponent.razor.cs` and make sure it is created in the **same folder** as the `MyComponent.razor`. If all works fine, the file should be added as a sub-file or `MyComponent.razor.cs`...
2. Open `MyComponent.razor.cs`. Make sure that the namespace is the same as the component (should be ok if the class was created in the same folder)
3. Mark the class as `public partial` and add your constraints

   // make sure namespaces match
   public partial class MyComponent where TItem : MyBaseClass, new() {

And that's it. And even better, I can now inject a generic service to my component to the `MyComponent.razor` component:

```
@typeparam TItem

@inject MyGenericService<TItem> _genericService;
```

Note that I registered the service in `Startup.cs` as a singleton (didn't test scoped but should work as well)...

```
// --- `Startup.cs` code
services.AddSingleton(new MyGenericService<MyObject>());
```

Hope this works for others, it made my generic CRUD forms SO MUCH easier to deal with and saved huge amount of duplicate code and weird switches to infert type from generic control!

Comment: can't format the code after point 3 properly... what am I doing wrong?!

Comment: public partial class MyComponent<TItem> where TItem : class {}